# FastAPI 405 method not allowed when creating forms in html

Tags: python, fastapi

I created a tool in flask, but want to move it to fastapi. I defined two routes as follows:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse


@app.get("/mytool")
async def home(request: Request, response_class=HTMLResponse):
    # displays tool 
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index_tool.html", {"request": request})


@app.post("/mytool")
async def home(request: Request, 
               var1: str = Form(), 
               var2: str = Form(), 
               var3: int = Form(), 
               var4: int = Form()):

    # ... perform calculation 
    result = myCalculation(var1, var2, var3, var4)
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index_tool.html", {"request": request, 
                                                          "result": result})
```

However, whenever I submit the form. It gives the error `POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 Method Not Allowed`, even though I defined both the `GET` and `POST` route. How should I go about creating such a tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few issues. You're using the same method name (`home`) for both the post and the get endpoint - this will make it hard to use `url_for` in your templates to get the actual endpoint from a route name.

Your `POST` in the log is against `/`, not against `/mytool` which is the path you've registered in your code.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 Method Not Allowed
     ^
```

vs

```
@app.post("/mytool")
           ^^^^^^^
```

Since you haven't included your actual template where the `form` element defines where the submission should be sent, you should probably replace it with something like:

```
<form method="post">
```

.. if the URL is the same, or if you fix the function names, you can do:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('home_calculate') }}">
```

Comment: silly me, it was caused by the same method name. Too busy looking for problems elsewhere.